# How to wait for click then close the Splashscreen in WPF application?

Tags: wpf, screen, splash-screen

I have a WPF Application and there's a button which shows an image (Splash Screen) containing the company logo and the name of the developers of the application. I want this image be shown until the user interacts with whatever. When user clicks or enters a keyboard key, the image must close. Refer to the comment line in my code.

```
private void Info_BeforeCommandExecute(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    SplashScreen SS = new SplashScreen("Images/InfotecSplashScreenInfo.png");
    SS.Show(false);

    // Need to do something here to wait user to click or press any key

    SS.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}
```

Comment: May I ask when this splash screen is supposed to be invoked?  Application startup? Clicking a button? hmm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a handler for the Keyboard class using [AddKeyDownHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.addkeydownhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
private void Info_BeforeCommandExecute(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    SplashScreen SS = new SplashScreen("Images/InfotecSplashScreenInfo.png");
    SS.Show(false);

    KeyEventHandler handler;
    handler = (o,e) =>
    {
          Keyboard.RemoveKeyDownHandler(this, handler);
          SS.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    };

    Keyboard.AddKeyDownHandler(this, handler);        
}
```

This would allow you to close the splash screen after the user presses a key.

Comment: Thanks Reed Copsey. What is the "(o,e)" parameters? I didn't get it.

Comment: @FredNetview The `(o,e)` is part of a lambda expression - saves you from having to write a separate method for that.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Reed's answer is no doubt easiest, but you could also avoid using SplashScreen altogether and just use a custom Window to give you full control.

**YourCode.cs**

```
private void Info_BeforeCommandExecute(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    SplashWindow SS = new SplashWindow();
    SS.ShowDialog(); // ShowDialog will wait for window to close before continuing
}
```

**SplashWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication14.SplashWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="SplashWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <!-- Your Image here, I would make a Custom Window Style with no border and transparency etc. -->
        <Button Content="Click Me" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**SplashWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class SplashWindow : Window
{
    public SplashWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Once user clicks now we can close the window 
        // and/or add keyboard handler
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dirt. I made this way, but the Reed Copsey's solution also worked fine. Everyone thanks!